# Cron expression for one day occurs every hour

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I need cron expression which allows to me run scheduler by the following rules:

```
Starts 12:00 am on Friday (pacific time) 
ends 12:00 am on Saturday (pacific time)
And between these two dates it must occurs every hour
```

i can write something like `"0 0 12/1 ? * FRI-SAT"` but ofcourse it is not correct. 
How to set simple range from 12-00 FRI to 12-00 SAT?

Comment: the ? symbol could be replaced by 00, the FRI-SAT already is a time period. But I don't know what you mean thid 12/1 do you what to run the command every hour ?

Comment: @Edorka 12/1 means 12:00, 13:00, 14:00...etc. We increment start hours by one hour.

Comment: ok but i thik that the order fields are: 
minutes, hours, day of the month, month, week day

Answer (score 2):

Try this expression

```
0 0 12-23,00-12 ? * FRI,SAT
```

and you can verify the next scheduled time here at http://www.cronmaker.com/ by entering this expression.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that you will probably need to set up two triggers, one that starts at 12:00 pm Friday and ends at midnight and triggers every hour and one for Saturday starting at 00:00 am and ends at 12:00 pm. So something like this

```
0 0 12-23 ? * FRI
0 0 0-12 ? * SAT
```

[Cron Trigger Tutorial](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/crontrigger)
**Edit**
Also have a look at [Cron Maker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) as it will generate the cron expression for you. and also show when it will trigger.

Comment: Thanks. Is it real to merge these expressions to one expression?

Comment: I suppose you could try 0 0 12-23,00-12 ? * FRI,SAT but i have no idea if it would work or that it would trigger on the times you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

If a cron expression is not easily discernible you can always build your own trigger.

I'm thinking something like this may help:

```
    var jobDetail;

    var days = new DayOfWeek[] {DayOfWeek.Friday, DayOfWeek.Saturday};

    var trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .ForJob(jobDetail)
        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInHours(1)
        .OnDaysOfTheWeek(days)
        .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(0, 0)));
```